# ios не работает .match

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В загрузке странички аяксом использую регулярку. Везде работает кроме IOS. У яблок на этой строке перестаёт выполняться скрипт. Диагностировал место путем расставления алертов в разных местах.
Собственно строка с проблемой.

```
 var classes = data.match(/<body class="([\w\s-]*)"/s);
```

И так со всеми регулярками, ужас.
Кто подскажет где копать? как решать?

try catch говорит invalid flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код `var classes = data.match(/<body class="([\w\s-]*)"/s);` работает только в последних версиях Chrome, в котором уже реализованы некоторые возможности стандарта ECMAScript 2018. В частности, реализована поддержка флага `s`, "DOTALL", который необходим в том случае, когда шаблон `.` должен находить любые знаки, включая знаки перевода строки (по умолчанию точка не находит такие знаки).

В ECMAScript5 и ECMAScript6 для нахождения любого знака можно использовать `[^]` или `[\s\S]` / `[\w\W]` / `[\d\D]`.

Так как в регулярном выражении `<body class="([\w\s-]*)"` нет `.`, флаг `s` не нужен.

Флаг `i` может пригодиться, если текст содержит `body class` и `BODY CLASS`.